# Difference between "shared" and "standard" in Swift singletons?

Tags: swift, singleton

To retrieve the shared or singleton instance of a class, I commonly see syntax in one of two forms: `className.standard` or `className.shared`.

Example:

```
UserDefaults.standard    // Returns the shared defaults object. (from docs)
UIApplication.shared     // Returns the singleton app instance. (from docs)
```

Is there a difference? Why does Swift use both routinely? Which one should I use when I create a singleton?

Comment: From my anecdotes, `shared` typically means that this is the only instance you should use, and you should not create any new instances (e.g. there is only one `UIApplication` instance that you should use, creating a new `UIApplication` throws an exception). Any other name implies that you are allowed to create other instances (e.g. creating your own `UserDefaults` with a custom suite name is fine). `Bundle.main` implies that there are bundles that are not the main bundle, etc. I'm not sure if this is a consistent rule though.

Comment: Why would the docs say `UserDefaults.standard` "returns the _shared_ defaults object" if "shared" is reserved for cases where you should not create your own instance. Typo perhaps?

Comment: @Eric33187 The _instance_ of the standard user defaults domain is shared, but you can still create your own with a given domain name (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init); as opposed to, e.g., `UIApplication` which you cannot create another instance of. This is a general pattern but not a hard rule.

Answer (score 0):

By calling the standard property you retrieve the shared defaults object, in which we can read and write the key-value pairs. To store a value first, you need to declare its key. A key is a unique string that identifies a value in the UserDefaults.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).